How can I centre the Python window on the launch of a script on Windows?
Title is self explanatory. I was trying to accomplish this for a long time with varied answers, but no definitive one.
The issue is, how is it possible to centre the python window to the display on the launch of a script?
For example, I have a script that has multiple functions in it where on function selected, kills the current script and launches the script for that said function. I wanted each time that script is launched to be launched in the MIDDLE of the screen and not in the top right, top left or vice versa, where new windows like to be automatically placed.
I've tried pywin32, since I use Windows and using win32gui.MoveWindow("python.exe", 0, 0, 500, 500, True) to do it yet it leads to the "TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object" error. I was expecting it to centre to 0, 0 on the screen, which I presume is the middle of the display. I haven't tried Tkinter because I don't need a separate GUI.
How can I do it on Windows?
